# Why this code does not produce a typescript error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following example:

```
type Bar = {
    foo: (x: number, y: number) => number;
};

const Test = (): Bar => {
    const foo = (): number => {
        return 1;
    };
    return {
        foo,
    };
};
```

This snippet passes typescript compilation and I don't understand why.

Test is a function that returns Bar.

Bar is an object which must have a function foo with the specified arguments and return type.

I'm expecting a typescript error here....

Play with it in typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBW1AZge3wC4oAKADxIDsBXAWwCMIEAaKEa+phAShQD4otRswDcGAL7iAxvioBnYFAAqERSjI8S8JMkGYcUWQqUF8G0lqFdmA9FkM4EEYDQRUoARnGGpD7M6u7vaOOGYs-lB+UkA

Comment: A function that takes `void` and returns a number is still assignable to a function that takes two numbers and returns a number. [See here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: Because the types don't actually *conflict*. That function *can* receive two numerical parameters, it'll just ignore them. It would only be a problem if `foo` took parameters whose types didn't accept a number.

Answer (score -2):

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters (emphasis mine):

> ### Optional and Default Parameters
>
> In TypeScript, every parameter is assumed to be required by the function. This doesn’t mean that it can’t be given null or undefined, but rather, **when the function is called, the compiler will check that the user has provided a value for each parameter**. The compiler also assumes that these parameters are the only parameters that will be passed to the function. In short, the number of arguments given to a function has to match the number of parameters the function expects.

So, after your code, this works

```
console.log(Test())
```

but this gives a compilation error

```
console.log(Test().foo())
```